# Go extension causing errors, not able to write the code properly

Tags: go, vscode-extensions

[checkout the gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0lx6.gif)

I recently decided to learn Golang/go, understanding concepts, and find it amazing till now, but I face issues with go extension developed by go.dev. the issues faced here in the file shared are also written below:

1. I understand, that IntelliSense is trying to write and format the code in a more prettier manner, but it affects by not letting it be added (by pressing enter and then writing something).
2. Here in "const Locktovars", I wanted to write a datatype 'string' or let's assume something else, but it is not letting me do it, instead it is trying to omit the additional spaces I added (though I can use copilot to complete the line with a 'tab' but I'm trying to learn it manually).
3. A doubt: before all this mess, why am I seeing the 'red underline' at package main when everything I write is syntactically and logically correct?
   I don't know if it's a good thing or not, or maybe just happening with me, but its quite irritating (pls note, I've already tried previous versions of the extensions as try-fail)

Here's my os type(if it matters)

```
    ~$ cat /etc/os-release
    PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
    NAME="Ubuntu"
    VERSION_ID="22.04"
    VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
    VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
    ID=ubuntu
    ID_LIKE=debian
    UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

please tell me what should i do, i guess its just a random bug which can be easily dealt with

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. If you have more than one Go program in the folder, it will underline func main because it's not unique, try putting them in separate folders. If you don't have a go.mod file, it will not compile and give you an error in the debug console. Configuring workspaces is the likely candidate for fixing the underlining of the package main statement. Hopefully something in here points you in the right direction.

Edit: Didn't see the gif at first, sorry about that. The stuttering might be an electron issue in Ubuntu. I can't reproduce it but I'll spin a machine with that version on it and see if I can reproduce it. The squiggle under the package main is workspace related but you can still compile and run just fine with that.

Comment: For the part of creating separate folders, I changed and it did work, (thanks for that.)
but this stuttering is just too much frustration. Whenever I write try writing a new file,
it automatically enters a new line after 'package m'.
as of now, I'm working on it without the extension, but I wonder, how would I be able to cope up when I start building some projects in go